# Approximate the integral $\int_0^\pi \sin(x^3)\mathrm{d}x$ with a standard pocket calculator

Tags: integration, approximation

I came over the following integral
$$
  \int_0^\pi \sin(x^3) \mathrm{d}x
$$
when a friend of mine tried to approximate it. 
The most obvious way is to use taylors formula, and then turn the integral into a sum. Eg
$$
\int_0^\pi \sin(x^3) \mathrm{d}x \approx \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{1}{2} \frac{(-1)^k \pi^{3k+2}}{(3k+2)(2k+1)!}
$$
The problem is the nominator increases much more rapidly than the denominator for the first 30 terms or so. Much faster than what a standard calculator can deal with. 
This can be seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8aX0.jpg

By using the midpoint rule instead, the sum turns into 
$$
   \int_0^\pi \sin(x^3) \mathrm{d}x \approx \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=0}^N f\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2k-1}{N}\right)
$$
Which converges to two decimal places in $36$ iterations, however to obtain a higher accuracy the convergence is slower than the taylor series.

As a final note I also tried using the substitution $u \mapsto u^3$, but the series expansion did not improve.

**My question is as follows: What is the least terms needed to approximate the integral to $3$ digits accuracy under the restrictions of using a standard pocket calculator?**

To clearify the calculator does not have more than 8 digits accuracy, and can use sine and cosine. Oh, I also tried Simpsons that did not improve the convergence. Could Romberg, or Gaussian lead to faster convergence?

Comment: You will get better results using [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule) or [Boole's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_rule).  36 intervals gives you 3 digits with either of these methods.

Comment: Then where is my mistake here? http://i.imgur.com/Kj477Ey.jpg

Comment: You are using the midpoint rule; instead I advocate using a different, better, rule for numerical integration.

Comment: I added an image (hopefully clearly) showing me using the `simpsons rule` to approximate the integral. As seen it does not converge successfully to three correct digits neither after 36 or 100 iterations.

Comment: Your sums suggest that the interval is $[0,2\pi]$, not $[0,\pi]$ (you are not using Simpson's rule correctly).  See [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=estimate+integral+from+0+to+pi+of+sin%28x%5E3%29+with+simpson%27s+rule+using+36+intervals).